# Can I force all children inheriting a class to inherit a specific method?

Tags: java, inheritance

So, I have an abstract class acting as a parent class, here's what I want to happen.

In abstract class:

```
public void run(){
    while(!booleanStatement){
        //do specific stuff here
    }
}
```

In child class:

```
public class extends parentClass{
public void run(){
    //do child stuff here effected by the while loop above
}
```

Is there any way to make this happen?   super() maybe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure. Just define an additional abstract method:

```
public final void run(){
  while(!booleanStatement){
    doRun();
  }
}

public abstract void doRun();
```

In this scenario the subclass can't overwrite `run()` and is *forced* to provide an implementation for `doRun()` which does the work inside the loop.

Comment: Then in the child class I would just call run() from my doRun() method?

Comment: You shouldn't call it from within the `doRun()` method. The `doRun()` methods implements everything that shall be executed in the loop. Calling it from the `doRun()` method will probably lead to `StackOverflowException`s

Comment: So, just to be clear on this one.   The child classes are forced to implement doRun() to handle their stuff, but then simply call run, which then calls doRun() from inside the loop?

Comment: This is a design patter I use A LOT, especially when creating generic framework-type code.  I believe this would be Decorator?  Anyway, +1 to you sir.  I think this is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I'm liking this a lot, the more I think of it the better it seems in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calling `super.run()` will execute the parent's method.

So you can extend it by doing something like:

```
public void run() {
    super.run();
    //do child stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In abstract class:

```
public void run(){
    while(!booleanStatement){
        doStuff();
    }
}

protected abstract void doStuff();
```

In child class:

```
public class extends parentClass{
protected void doStuff() {
    // do something
}
```

Something like this will do.